# Reading JSON entity from JerseyClient response takes a long time

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy, jersey-client

Time between `read Entity` and `finish` logs in the code below takes about 5s. This is probably because every time I call `readEntity` JerseyClient is preparing JAXB context for that response. I do not do this anywhere in my code so probably it is done automatically by class scanning.

Is there any way I can register somehow my already prepared JAXB context to my JerseyClient and reuse it every time I call another service? ...or maybe there is another reason why this simple operation takes so much time.

```
JerseyClient client = new JerseyClientBuilder().property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, connectTimeout).property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, readTimeout).property(ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, false).register(MoxyJsonFeature.class).register(getMoxyJsonConfig().resolver()).build();
JerseyWebTarget target = client.target(path);
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.withCharset(getCharset().name())).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorization);
invocation = builder.buildGet();
Response response = invocation.invoke();

logger.info("Efficiency testing: read Entity");
T result = response.readEntity(returnClass);
logger.info("Efficiency testing: finish");
```